# What does 'with' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> This form of eavesdropping became common practice **with** rulers from many cultures. In English, the phrase "the walls have ears" was first recorded in its present form in the mid-1600s.  (From "Shhh! The Walls Have Ears!")

Does it mean 'by'?

Comment: Just to clarify, no, it doesn't mean 'by' because of the rest of the grammar of that sentence. Yes, you could express the same idea with _by_ and other words: _This form of eavesdropping was commonly practiced_ by _rulers from many cultures_. To make that work, though, you need to massage the verb and lose the sense of slow change.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means ['among'](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/among).

Rephrasing,

> Rulers from many cultures commonly practiced this form of eavesdropping.

Answer (score 1):

Another paraphrase of **with** in this context might be **attending** or **accompanying**.

> A problem with|attending high-performance cars is that they need
>   very frequent tune-ups.
>
> A problem that accompanies high-performance cars is that they need
>   very frequent tune-ups.

Much the same idea can be expressed with the possessive:

> *The problem with him* is that he gives up too soon.

paraphrase:

> **His** problem is that he gives up too soon.
>
> This form of eavesdropping was the common practice **of rulers** from many cultures.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Tromano](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/143902/52137) and [CinCout](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/143827/52137) are pointing at the right senses of *with* to match your question.

In this exact sentence, especially in translation, the best parallel would usually be **for** or **of**

> This form of eavesdropping became [the] common practice **for**/**of** rulers from many cultures.

but, like CinCout said, that's because the real sense is *among*: It was a practice *common among*/*shared by* that group of people. That use in turn was based on Tromano's: It was a practice that was *often found among* that group of people. Note how Tromano adjusted his own repetition of the sentence without quite noticing how he was changing both it and his answer.